# Hashtable<String,Integer[]> myhash = new Hashtable();

Tags: java, arrays, object, hashtable

I would like to know if it is possible to have this:

```
Hashtable<String,Integer[]> myhash =new Hashtable();
```

Where String would be a word, and the integer[], would be an array of two position, the first one, the line number and the second one would be the number of times this word apears.

But I don't really know how to do the put operation.

```
myhash.put(word, new Integer(n_line,n_times));??
```

It doesn't work, but how would you do it?

Thank you

Comment: It's an `Integer[]`, an integer **array**.

Comment: Also, if you only have two data elements, why not create a custom class to hold them instead of using an array? The code will be more descriptive.

Comment: BTW `Map<String, int[]>` would also work, and would probably suit you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put a new integer array into your table use `myhash.put(word, new Integer[]{ n_line,n_times});`

However, I'd advise to create a new object for the value, e.g.

```
//Note that I ommitted stuff like modifiers, constructors etc. for simplicity's sake
//In most cases you'd want to expand that class and add what's missing (left to you as an excercise)
class WordCounter {
  int lines;
  int time;
}

Hashtable<String,WordCounter > myhash =new Hashtable<>();
```

As a side note, keep in mind that `Hashtable` is slower than `HashMap` since it synchronizes access, so unless you need that exact behavior you might try and use  `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: As a further refinement, I'd make those variables `public final` and add a constructor.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's right, but I wanted to keep things simple, so I omitted the usual stuff like constructors etc. ;) - I'll add a comment.

Comment: Yes I will do something like this, but I wanted to see if the results I was getting were the right ones, before trying to do a nicer code and more effective. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

try

```
myhash.put(word, new Integer[] {n_line,n_times});
```

btw Hashtable is a legacy class, use HashMap instead

Comment: int n_line = myhash.get(word)[0]

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{n_line,n_times};
myhash.put(word, arr);
```